# How to prevent horizontal scrolling on responsive webpage?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm using twitter bootstrap to make my app responsive.  When I shrink the width of my browser window to the minimum size or view the page on a mobile device (iPhone, example), the user is able to scroll horizontally.  The amount of horizontal scroll is small but I would like to remove it all together.

I believe it's due to the img container that I'm including, but I'm not here.  The page's html is located here: http://pastebin.ca/2347946.

Any advice on how to prevent the horizontal scroll for the page while still maintaining the scrolling in the img container?

Comment: How can a CSS problem be solved without the CSS?  Pastebin won't last forever.

Comment: check your code and syntax as per bootstrap's documentation, you might have somewhere placed row, container or cols wrongly

Answer (score 31, accepted):

i am pretty sure somewhere one of your child element is exceeding the width of its parent element. Check you code twice, if there any box-size of inner child elements is large because of one of the reasons like- when the box width including `margin`, `padding`, `border` go beyond the limit. And we possibly haven't added `overflow: hidden;` to its outer parent element. In this case they are considered reaching beyond their parent element and browsers show it with the scrollbar. So fix it via removing extra margins, paddings, borders or if you just don't want any headache, just try to add `overflow:hidden;` to the outer box.

Comment: I tried doing what you recommended but wasn't sure where to look.  Do you know where I should include it on the page: http://warm-chamber-7399.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 40):

I had the same problem, and applied this to fix it:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
.container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

To expand a bit, I only had the problem on mobile phones, so this is my final code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 667px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 100% !important;
        overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
}
```

I found the issues regarding this on Github, so I guess newer versions of Bootstrap have been patched.

Answer (score 3):

The "overflow: hidden;" style is the remedy not the prevention. 
If you want to prevent this you have to check your body elements which is larger than the body.
It happens when you take a div with some "padding" or "margin" outside ".container" class (twitter bootstrap).
So remove all padding and margin outside the container class.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out I had zoomed in more than 100% that was causing the page to scroll. Cmd+0 helped bring the zoom to 100% which got rid of the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add (in the relevant `@-rule`) a `max-width`:

```
img {
    max-width: NNNpx;
}
```

That'll prevent `img` from being too wide.

Comment: I attempted to include this max-width attribute but wasn't sure where to include it.  Any advice given this page? http://warm-chamber-7399.herokuapp.com/

Comment: I wasn't sure which image you were referring to in your answer.