# How do I prevent my websites hamburger menu from letting people scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I wanted to know how I would go about preventing people on mobile from swiping sideways after they open and close my hamburger menu. It works fine before they open it but after it breaks and next time it closed they can scroll sideways. I've tried the things suggested on other questions to no avail. It's not a very big site yet so there isn't much there.

```
html, body {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Website: mostwantedrbx.github.io

Repo: https://github.com/MostwantedRBX/MostwantedRBX.github.io

Comment: There is no code in the question that demonstrates the issue; a [mre]. If I use that CSS on a blank HTML page, it's not going to do much.

Comment: Im not trying to argue, but minimal reproducible code would mean I would have to have the hamburger menu with the features it has to reproduce it because it makes the side bar go off the side of the page. When you open and close it it enabled you to scroll sideways. I felt like that would have been too much code to reproduce it. That is why I place the repo to the small website, my problem could have been from JavaScript, html or css. But my problem got fixed nonetheless. I appreciate the advice and help guys, I'll make sure I do that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the .nav-links a position of fixed instead of absolute.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 788px) {
.nav-links {
    position: fixed; /* instead of absolute */ 
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 8vh;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 30%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

this [might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35078427/15107749)

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
.container {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```